# 'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: windows-7, find

I am getting this error when I use the `FIND` function in a nested `FOR` loop and `IF` statements in a batch file.

> 'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

I am trying to find the biggest files in the directory:

```
SET /P number=Enter the number of files to find:

for /l %%x in (1,1,!number!) do (

for /r %%h in (*) do (
IF %%x GTR 1 IF !check! geq %%~zh (
IF !check! equ %%~zh (
echo !chkn!
FIND "!chkn!" Biggest.txt
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 set res=notfound
FIND "!chkp!" Biggest.txt
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 set res=notfound
IF "!res!" equ "notfound" (
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET  tes=%%~zh
SET  name=%%~nh
SET  path=%%~ph
)
)
)
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET  tes=%%~zh
SET  name=%%~nh
SET  path=%%~ph
)
)
IF %%x equ 1 (
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET  tes=%%~zh
SET  name=%%~nh
SET  path=%%~ph
)
)
)

SET check=!tes!
SET chkn=!name!
SET chkp=!path!

echo !chkn!
echo !check!

echo %%x number: >> Biggest.txt
echo name = !chkn! >> Biggest.txt
echo size = !check! >> Biggest.txt
echo path = !chkp! >> Biggest.txt
echo file is created
SET tes=0
)
```

Comment: you reset search path in your statements under some conditions. As soon as you do, cmd will not be able to find find (pun intended) and will fail. Change your `path` variable to different name

Comment: Yeah..you are correct!!! I need to change the variable 'path' to something else. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the lack of detail, I would guess your Find command doesn't use c:\windows\system32\

Does this work

```
SET /P number=Enter the number of files to find:

for /l %%x in (1,1,!number!) do (

for /r %%h in (*) do (
IF %%x GTR 1 IF !check! geq %%~zh (
IF !check! equ %%~zh (
echo !chkn!
c:\windows\system32\FIND "!chkn!" Biggest.txt
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 set res=notfound
c:\windows\system32\FIND "!chkp!" Biggest.txt
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 set res=notfound
IF "!res!" equ "notfound" (
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET  tes=%%~zh
SET  name=%%~nh
SET  path=%%~ph
)
)
)
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET  tes=%%~zh
SET  name=%%~nh
SET  path=%%~ph
)
)
IF %%x equ 1 (
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET  tes=%%~zh
SET  name=%%~nh
SET  path=%%~ph
)
)
)

SET check=!tes!
SET chkn=!name!
SET chkp=!path!

echo !chkn!
echo !check!

echo %%x number: >> Biggest.txt
echo name = !chkn! >> Biggest.txt
echo size = !check! >> Biggest.txt
echo path = !chkp! >> Biggest.txt
echo file is created
SET tes=0
)
```

Comment: But FIND is working when I am running some other batch file

Comment: Yeah....This worked. Thank you very much !! You are right but I don't know why FIND was working in other batch file.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: your solution works, but root cause is different than what you guessed (see my comment on question). Would you care to edit?